# Difference between "have to" and "must" regarding certainty

Tags: synonyms

They are alike "used to say that something is very likely" according to M-W Learner's. Then, is "must" replaceable for "had to" in the below? It comes at 11:00 in the NBC News in [this video](https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20220602_013000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20220602_013000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=1268/1328&exact=1&ignore=x.mp4):

> Now to that breakthrough treatment announced today in the New England
> Journal of Medicine for pancreatic cancer and the possibility it will
> help patients with other types of cancer as well. Here is NBC's Blayne
> Alexander.
>
> In early 2018, Kathy Wilks faced a grim prognosis -- stage three
> pancreatic cancer. She didn't know how long she **had to** live. Her
> treatment was grueling -- eight rounds of chemotherapy, surgery,
> radiation. “It was a lot of nausea, very tired, a lot of just… not
> wanting to get out of bed.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use *must* here, because this is a different kind of *had to*, and it is actually kind of an accident that *had* and *to* are next to each other.  This "had" means, essentially, "*possessed*", not "was required to".

We can use *to have* when we mean "possess", with a verb using the to-infinitive of a verb to indicate what we are doing with the thing we possess, like this:

> She *had* five months *to live*. (She would live for five months.)

> I *have* seven hundred dollars *to give away*. (I own seven hundred dollars and I have the purpose of giving them away.)

> They *will have* an amazing story *to share*.  (They will know an amazing story, which they can share.)

This can lead to situations in which it is not obvious which meaning of *have to* is intended - *must*, or *possess for the purpose of*.  You usually just have to tell by context.  In this case, is she being *required* to live by someone else?  That seems like a very strange thing to require.  Therefore, *must* is probably not the correct interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence

> She did not know how long she *had to* live.

does **not** mean:

> She did not know how long she *must* live.

In its entry for *live*, the [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/live) lists these definitions:

> **live** VERB INTRANSITIVE
>
>
> 1.  to be alive; have life
>
> 2.
>
> a.  to remain alive
>
> b.  to last; endure

The word *live* in the original sentence uses that sense found in definitions 2a and 2b. A rewording of the original sentence could be formed as follows:

> She did not know how long she ***had to live***.
> She did not know how long she ***would remain alive***.